# python setup.py install - error boost library file not found

Tags: python, c++, boost

I am trying to install a python package dimod. the command line to install is python setup.py install....it ran out the below error:

/usr/local/boost-1.74.0/include/boost/type_traits/add_pointer.hpp:12:10: fatal error:
'boost/type_traits/remove_reference.hpp' file not found
#include <boost/type_traits/remove_reference.hpp>
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I installed boost library in the path /usr/local/boost-1.74.0/...But it seems all my boost library files path is boost/......I am manually changing the include path....but it is too much work.

Could anyone give a hint what I should do? It seems a very trivial Library linking problem, isn't it?

Thanks.

Comment: It's probably just a matter of specifying the correct includes path.  You haven't shown the command line that is compiling this.  It should have `-I/usr/local/boost-1.74.0/include/`

Comment: python setup.py install -I/usr/local/boost-1.74.0/include/ does not work... I have not found the make file....to include -I/usr/local/boost-1.74.0/include/.... do you know what executable scripts the command 'python setup.py install' calls?

Comment: I was not talking about the python command line.  I'm talking about the call that is invoking the C++ compiler.  Regarding what `setup.py` actually does, read the code.